# AWS Cognito | Custom Auth Flow | How to validate if device is tracked

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

In Cognito, I have defined a simple custom authentication flow.
The "define auth challenge" function is below:

```
func Handler(ctx context.Context, event *events.CognitoEventUserPoolsDefineAuthChallenge) (*events.CognitoEventUserPoolsDefineAuthChallenge, error) {
    if len(event.Request.Session) == 1 && event.Request.Session[0].ChallengeName == "SRP_A" {
        event.Response.IssueTokens = false
        event.Response.FailAuthentication = false
        event.Response.ChallengeName = "PASSWORD_VERIFIER"
    }

    if len(event.Request.Session) == 2 && event.Request.Session[1].ChallengeName == "PASSWORD_VERIFIER" {
        event.Response.IssueTokens = true
        event.Response.FailAuthentication = false
    }
    return event, nil
}
```

The user pool has configured "track devices" to "always".

**Question:** How can I check if the device, from which the user attempts to sign in, as a new device or already tracked?

I use Amplify on the front end.